# carousel plugin / setup / code embed

Tags: carousel

I'd like to add in a carousel feature within the body of a webpage. I have successfully embedded generated code from sites where i've generated a small animation but i can't seem to find anything online for a carousel - there are older entries i've come across which mention doing this with native EE function but the posts are several years old. help?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do a gallery with the grid fieldtype and any number of jquery (or other) slider plugins.

Comment: i'm admittedly very new to expression engine - where might i get such a plugin? when i google these things the posts relating to them are all from 2012 or 2014

Comment: grid is a default fieldtype included in (at least) EE3. for EE2 grid might be available in EE2.x but i can't remember. but updating to EE3 is advised anyway

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you need to find a carousel script and then have EE output the contents that the carousel will display.

There are many carousel plugins that typically run via jQuery.  Personally, I use owlcarousel https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Once your carousel plugin is installed and is working on your page you can setup your EE tags to start displaying your content. Most carousels use a simple ul li structure where each li item is a photo or other info.
For outputting these things via EE, you would simply use channel:entries and output your fields content - standard text with a link to an image, an image or file field or grid content. You could have an EE grid field that contains an image, a link, text description or whatever. Once you have an entry setup, you would just structure your tags to format that output to replace the html the carousel is expecting.  Use the EE tags to randomize, limit, display by category, etc.

Hope this helps.